# How to name an anonymous function to the property it was assigned to?

Tags: javascript

Apologies for the incomprehensible question. What I mean is far better illustrated in code.

Given the following:

```
{

    functionA: function(){
     ...
    },

    functionB: function(){
     ...
    },

    functionC: function(){
     ...
    },
}
```

Is it possible to somehow at runtime get a structure like so?:

```
{

    functionA: function functionA(){
     ///
    },

    functionB: function functionB(){
     ///
    },

    functionC: function functionC(){
     ///
    },
}
```

The resulting functions may be wrapper-functions.

Background: given an MVC-framework in which users can define arbitrary controller functions (which they usually do of the anonymous kind), I want to be able to generate a map of all `url endpoints -> controller functions`  defined. This would only be useful if I can somehow extract the name of the variable to which the anonymous function is defined, since having all *url endpoints* map to `anonymous function` would not be that insightful.

**to clarify**: based on the extension points of the MVC I can't build the url->function map in another way and have to resort to being able to name the functions.

Comment: those are nearly equivalent.

Comment: You should probably just store a variable which keeps track of which function was used.

Comment: Function expressions are allowed to have names in JavaScript, so couldn't you type just that?

Comment: You can't just iterate over the object to get the property names to which the anonymous functions are assigned?

Comment: @Jordan Exactly. Why make these functions properties of some object, if not for names? If naming's not important, you can just place them all into an array, after all. )

Comment: @Jordan: I agree that would be the best thing to do, but I'm constrained to the hooks the MVC gives me. This gives me access to the controllers (which I could then modify as per above), but doesn't give me the controllers and the routing-config to map them. Hmm, I realize this is an awful explanation :)

Comment: @Jordan: the code in which the mvc maps controller-functions to url-endpoints is opaque to me. I can only view the *input* (the controller  with anonymous functions as described) and the *output* (the mapping of the url-endpoints -> controller functions.) It would make sense to use the *output* but this data-structure no longer contains the propertynames to which the anonymous functions were originally bound.  I therefore cannot use the *output* to iterate the functions. Hope that makes any sense.

Comment: @raina77ow: naming using properties is used by the mvc to, for instance, declaratively bind access-policies to the functions. It's not my mvc btw, I just try to extend it giving the hooks I'm given. I realize that if I had access to all the code I could just hack this in by iterating as Jordan suggested.